# Search - handling empty criteria fields

Tags: php, mysql, search

I would need some structure suggestions for **fast** multiple criteria search.
There are input fields for all table columns to search by.

How to handle empty fields (not filled by user / only search by given information)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is

```
WHERE
(col1=@col1 or @col1 is null) and
(col2=@col2 or @col2 is null) and
(col3=@col3 or @col3 is null) and
.
.
```

assuming you pass null if the column is skipped for search

Answer (score 0):

You can build and append the where clause as below

```
$query ="SELECT fields FROM tableName ";
$where ="";

 if(isset($_POST['field1']))
 {
   $field1=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field1']);
   if($field1 != '')
   {
      $where . = "field1Name = $field1 AND ";
   }
 } 
   if(isset($_POST['field2']))
 {
   $field2=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field2']);
   if($field2 != '')
   {
      $where . = "field2Name = $field2 AND ";
   }
 } 

 $where = rtrim($where, " AND ");
 $query . =$where;
```

Comment: You're building SQL out of unfiltered bits of $_POST.  What happens when someone goes searching for `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` ?